# Not able to find files and images under src directory

Tags: java

In my program, I have three folders listed under src directory: files, sound, images. I am not sure why my code did not detected.  When I run the program, I got this message: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: files\7.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)".  I have image attached here.  Please help.

below is my code:

```
package riddle;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;

public class Math_Riddle extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
/**
*
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JLabel lblQuestion;
JLabel lblImage;
JButton bOK;
JButton bExit;
JPanel radioPanel;
JPanel panBottom;
JRadioButton[] radioButton;
String [] store ;
ButtonGroup bg;
JButton bNext;
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel pRight;
JLabel lblCorrect;
JLabel lblWrong;
int vCorrect = 0;
int vWrong = 0;
public Math_Riddle()
{
mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
buildingGUI();
listAllFiles();
innitializeAllComponents();
int fileNumber = generateRandomNumber();
String filePath = "files/" + fileNumber + ".txt";
String strQuestion = readTextFile(filePath);
store = strQuestion.toString().split("!!!");
lblQuestion.setText("<html>" + store[0] + "</html>");
//I need to get the image and display at the center according
//to the fileNumber;
getTheImageAndDisplay(fileNumber);
assignRandomNumberToRadioButton(store[1]);
mainPanel.add(lblQuestion, BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
mainPanel.add(panBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
mainPanel.add(lblImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
}

private void listAllFiles()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
File file = new File(".");
for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);
}

private void getTheImageAndDisplay(int fileNumber)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String filePath = "images/";
lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(filePath + fileNumber + ".png"));
}

private void assignRandomNumberToRadioButton(String sAnswer)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int number  = Integer.parseInt(sAnswer.toString().trim());
System.out.println("number: " + number);
Random random = new Random();
int rand = random.nextInt(4); //This is the number of radioButton.
System.out.println("rand is: " + rand);
radioButton[rand].setText(sAnswer);

if(!radioButton[0].getText().equals(""))
{
    radioButton[1].setText("" +( number + 2));
    radioButton[2].setText("" + (number - 2));
    radioButton[3].setText("" + (number + 1));
}
else if(!radioButton[1].getText().equals(""))
{
    radioButton[0].setText("" +( number + 2));
    radioButton[2].setText("" + (number - 2));
    radioButton[3].setText("" + (number + 1));
}
else if(!radioButton[2].getText().equals(""))
{
    radioButton[1].setText("" +( number + 2));
    radioButton[0].setText("" + (number - 2));
    radioButton[3].setText("" + (number + 1));
}
else if(!radioButton[3].getText().equals(""))
{
    radioButton[1].setText("" +( number + 2));
    radioButton[2].setText("" + (number - 2));
    radioButton[0].setText("" + (number + 1));
}
}

/**
* Construct GUI.
*/
private void buildingGUI()
{
lblImage = new JLabel();
bNext = new JButton("Next");
lblQuestion = new JLabel();
bOK = new JButton("OK");
bExit = new JButton("Exit");
lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
radioPanel = new JPanel();
panBottom = new JPanel();
panBottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
panBottom.add(bOK);
panBottom.add(bExit);
bg = new ButtonGroup();
radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
radioButton = new JRadioButton[4];
radioButton[0] = new JRadioButton();
radioButton[1] = new JRadioButton();
radioButton[2] = new JRadioButton();
radioButton[3] = new JRadioButton();
radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
radioPanel.add(radioButton[0]);
radioPanel.add(radioButton[1]);
radioPanel.add(radioButton[2]);
radioPanel.add(radioButton[3]);
radioPanel.add(new JLabel());
radioPanel.add(new JLabel());
radioPanel.add(new JLabel());
radioPanel.add(bNext);
radioPanel.add(new JLabel());
radioPanel.add(new JLabel());
bg.add(radioButton[0]);
bg.add(radioButton[1]);
bg.add(radioButton[2]);
bg.add(radioButton[3]);
pRight = new JPanel();
pRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
lblCorrect = new JLabel();
pRight.add(lblCorrect);
lblWrong = new JLabel();
pRight.add(lblWrong);
pRight.add(new JLabel("                   "));
pRight.add(new JLabel("                   "));
mainPanel.add(pRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
}

private int generateRandomNumber()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Random random = new Random();
int rand = random.nextInt(20);  //This is the number of Files in the system.
return rand;
}

private void innitializeAllComponents()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
CompoundBorder border;
Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
Border loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( raisedbevel, loweredbevel);
lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
lblQuestion.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
lblQuestion.setBorder(border);
radioPanel.setBorder(border);
pRight.setBorder(border);
panBottom.setBorder(border);
radioButton[0].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
radioButton[1].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
radioButton[2].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
radioButton[3].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
lblCorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
lblCorrect.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
lblCorrect.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
lblWrong.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
lblWrong.setForeground(Color.red);
lblWrong.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
bNext.addActionListener(this);
}
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private static String readTextFile(String fileName)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
BufferedReader reader;
try
{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try
    {
        while(( line = reader.readLine()) != null )
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(ae.getSource().equals(bNext))
{
    //if nothing selected, display a message,
    //else: get the answer and display.
    if(!radioButton[0].isSelected() && !radioButton[1].isSelected() &&
            !radioButton[2].isSelected() && !radioButton[3].isSelected())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select an Answer.", "Nothing selected",
                JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        return;
    }
    else //when user select an answer.
    {
        String strAnswer = "";
        if(radioButton[0].isSelected())
        {
            strAnswer = radioButton[0].getText().trim();
        }
        else if(radioButton[1].isSelected())
        {
            strAnswer = radioButton[1].getText().trim();
        }
        else if(radioButton[2].isSelected())
        {
            strAnswer = radioButton[2].getText().trim();
        }
        else if(radioButton[3].isSelected())
        {
            strAnswer = radioButton[3].getText().trim();
        }
        if(strAnswer.equals(store[1].trim()))
        {
            String strCorrect = lblCorrect.getText();
            if(strCorrect.equals(""))
            {
                strCorrect = "0";
            }
            vCorrect = Integer.parseInt(strCorrect);
            vCorrect = vCorrect + 1;
            lblCorrect.setText("" + vCorrect);
            playSound("correct");
        }
        else
        {
            String strWrong = lblWrong.getText();
            if(strWrong.equals(""))
            {
                strWrong = "0";
            }
            vWrong = Integer.parseInt(strWrong);
            vWrong = vWrong + 1;
            lblWrong.setText("" + vWrong);
            playSound("wrong");
        }
        int fileNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        String filePath = "files\\" + fileNumber + ".txt";
        System.out.println("filePath: " + filePath);
        String strQuestion = readTextFile(filePath);
        store = strQuestion.toString().split("!!!");
        lblQuestion.setText("<html>" + store[0] + "</html>");
        System.out.println("store[0] is: " + store[0]);
        System.out.println("store[1]" + store[1]);
        clearTextInAllRadioButtons();
        assignRandomNumberToRadioButton(store[1]);
        getTheImageAndDisplay(fileNumber);
    }
}
}

private void playSound(String sound)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try
{
    URL url = null;
    if(sound.equals("correct"))
    {
        url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/ding.wav");
    }
    else if(sound.equals("wrong"))
    {
        url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/buzz.wav");
    }
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    // Get a sound clip resource.
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
}
catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (LineUnavailableException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private void clearTextInAllRadioButtons()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
radioButton[0].setText("");
radioButton[1].setText("");
radioButton[2].setText("");
radioButton[3].setText("");
bg.clearSelection();
}

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] s)
{
Math_Riddle mr = new Math_Riddle();
mr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mr.pack();
mr.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

---

About the File file = new File(resource.toURI());
here is what I tried but still did not work:

```
URL url = null;
Random rand = new Random();
int random = rand.nextInt(19);
String filePath = "files/" + random + ".txt";
System.out.println("file: " + filePath);
url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
System.out.println(url.toString().trim());
try
{
File file = new File(url.toURI());
}
catch (URISyntaxException e1)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
File folder = new File(".");
for(String fileNames : folder.list())
{
System.out.println(fileNames);
}
BufferedReader reader;
try
{
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String line = null;
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
try
{
while(( line = reader.readLine()) != null )
{
stringBuilder.append(line);
stringBuilder.append(ls);
}
}
catch (IOException e)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Below is the error message in eclipse:

file: files/5.txt
file:/C:/JavaProject/Tesing/bin/files/5.txt
.classpath
.project
.settings
bin
images
src
java.io.FileNotFoundException: files\5.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source)
    at Testing.actionPerformed(Testing.java:72)

when I tried to list all the files/folder.  It only listed the folder: bin, images, src....as you see above.
Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you narrow it down to only the most relevant parts?

Comment: Why are you putting all this UI code for setting fonts and layouts? Do you think that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying resource files with paths. That only works if you actually know the full path or the relative path from current directory; e.g. prepended with "src" as suggested in another answer.

It is, however,  much better to include resources in your build (whether you build through your IDE or an external build system like gradle or maven) so that these files are copied into the classpath (it may be that you're already doing this). In this case, you can retrieve the resources using the Java classloader, like this:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource");
```

A couple of notes here:

1. The leading "/" specifies that the classloader should search from the root package. If it is ommitted, it will search relative from the package of the class you're in.
2. You're getting a URL instead of a File. Quite often, it is possible to use these URL's directly, like in the `ImageIcon` contructor that you're using. One additional benefit with this method is that it works if your application is packaged in jar file as well, since then the URL will point into the correct location in the jar file. However, if you *know* it is a file, *and* you need the file reference, it can be converted like this: `File file = new File(resource.toURI());`.

EDIT: The following is an example that should work for Danny, based on his "answer" post with an example.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        new ResourceTest().test();
    }

    public void test() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("files/1.txt");
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        File file = new File(url.toURI());
        System.out.println("FILE: " + file);

        File folder = file.getParentFile();
        System.out.println("FOLDER: " + folder);
        System.out.println("FOLDER LIST: ");
        for (String fileName : folder.list()) {
            System.out.println("  " + fileName);
        }

        System.out.println("FILE CONTENTS:");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Which for yields the following output:

```
URL: file:/home/steinar/Safe/source/private/out/production/files/1.txt
FILE: /home/steinar/Safe/source/private/out/production/files/1.txt
FOLDER: /home/steinar/Safe/source/private/out/production/files
FOLDER LIST: 
  1.txt
FILE CONTENTS:
This is
my test
text file
```

Comment: here is what I tried but I did not work: URL url = null;
  Random rand = new Random();
  int random = rand.nextInt(19);
  String filePath = "files/" + random + ".txt";
  System.out.println("file: " + filePath);
  url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
  System.out.println(url.toString().trim());
  File file = new File(".");
  for(String fileNames : file.list())
  {
   System.out.println(fileNames);
  } help please

Comment: sorry for the messy format.  I could not press the Enter key to make new line.  If I press the Enter key, It just automatically save the comment and did not make new line.

Comment: Well, you're saying it didn't work, but you're not saying what happened. Your code example contains a mixture of choosing random files, resolving a URL and also listing a file path. Can you tell the the output of this: `System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("files/1.txt"));` If this is `null` then the resource is not copied into the classpath; then you'll need to tell me how you are running (command line? in your IDE? which tool / commands do you use). I'm assuming here that the file 1.txt exists and is in the files folder in your source directory. Is that the case?

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am desperate to get this to work.  I am 100% sure that the "files/1.txt" exit in the directory.  files directory contains: "0,txt, 1.txt .... 20.txt".  I am running this from eclipse.  Here is the step: right click in the Text Editor area, run as, Java Application.

Comment: @DannyPhung : From the output described in your "answer", it seems that you get a valid url, but you don't use this as starting point for retrieving the folder. Note that `File folder = new File(.)` will return the folder for the start directory of the application. I'll update my answer to include an example that should work for you.